# Controller on dropdown_search

Tags: android, flutter, controller, dropdown

I have flutter project working with Firestore database.
I can't retrieve value when using dropdown search .
With using `TextField` is like this :

```
TextField(
  controller: myController,
```

It's successfully saved into my firestore.
But, How to add controller into dropdown_search?

Answer (score 0):

You can access values through onChanged method of the widget.

```
   DropdownSearch(
      items: ["Brazil", "France", "Tunisia", "Canada"],
      label: "Country",
      onChanged: (value){
        print(value);
      },
      selectedItem: "Tunisia",
      validator: (String item) {
        if (item == null)
          return "Required field";
        else if (item == "Brazil")
          return "Invalid item";
        else
          return null;
      },
    );
```